Saxon 9.7 issue with xslt call to java method
I have an existing xslt that seemed to run fine in previous versions of saxon, but not longer runs on 9.7.  Here is what java call out looks like
xmlns:jfunc="java:package.functions.myfunction" 

<xsl:when test="boolean($callFunction)"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="jfunc:myMethod(n1:ParentNode/node())"/>
</xsl:when>

Here is the error that im getting
Cannot convert XPath value to Java object: required class is org.w3c.dom.Node; supplied value has type element(ns1:ChildNode, xs:untyped)

myMethod takes org.w3c.dom.Node as its parm.
Any thoughts or suggestions on this?

What does previous versions of Saxon refer to exactly? And why do you expect a DOM node in the world of XSLT/XPath? Do you run Saxon from Java? There you might be able to ensure you use a DOM document and not a Saxon XDM document node as the input, for instance by choosing a different object/tree model. But DOM for Saxon is usually considered to have several disadvantages like poor performance.

Sorry, we using saxon 94

Are you using Saxon from the command line? Or from your own Java code? If you expect to run XSLT against a W3C DOM then I think you need to make sure you build a DOM document as the input and for instance wrap it with https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/DocumentBuilder.html#wrap(java.lang.Object).

Thank you for the direction. I will look at upgrading the code.  In the meantime though, not sure why this would work in earlier versions but fail now.  Seems like saxon should still support passing a node to java for parsing.

Yes, you can pass a node but it will be a net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmNode. Or a NodeInfo. Expecting a DOM Node might have worked earlier, not sure at which point that changed. I am sure Michael Kay will tell you later.

https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/extensibility/functions/converting-args/converting-node.html is also relevant perhaps, although it partly suggests that a DOM wrapper should be created automatically if the method expects a DOM node.

Both 9.4 and 9.7 are ancient history (and no longer supported), so answering this question requires some serious archaeology.
I can't see anything in the change log that explicitly addresses this point.
I see that the 12.x documentation at  https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!extensibility/extension-functions-J/reflexive-functions/converting-args/converting-node does say

In addition, in the case of DOM only, if the XPath node is not a view
of a DOM node, Saxon will create a DOM wrapper for the native Saxon
node, and pass this wrapper.

I suggest you put together a repro demonstrating the problem on a currently-supported Saxon release (preferably 12.4) and if it doesn't work, raise an issue at saxonica.plan.io.
Both the documentation and Martin's response emphasise that mixing DOM and XDM data models can be difficult and have poor performance, and there can also be configuration issues, but I think it ought to work in theory.
Later...
I've checked that it's working in 12.4 - no problems. But there aren't many tests, so the devil will be in the detail.
